# After requesting a TCP connection request to a server, can client receive the reply on another port generated by server at its end

Tags: tcp, network-protocols, embedded

When TCP client requests conn'n on server's listening port, server will accept it and create a new port meant for this conn'n with this client. Hence forth the client will communicate with server on this new port.

if the above statement is true and possible, how server conveys the newly generated port to client. In reply to the conn'n request the packet from server to client will have what port as source port (Server's listening port OR New port generated by server for client). 
Will Client accept this port and take into use or it will give error ? I need this to implement an architecture having 2 clients and one server in an embedded system using lwip stack.

regards,
ED

Answer (score 2):

The server doesn't create a new port. It creates a new TCP *connection* and it sends its reply packets to the IP and port the client sent its connection request from. (A TCP connection has an IP address *and port* on each side.)

Comment: I am asking this question asi need to implement this in an embedded system using lwip stack 

*When the client has sent a connection request on server's listening port, i presume it will expect the reply from server having server's listening port as source port in the header. Then how will the client come to know about the new tcp connection details(specifically port number).

Comment: The client will know the destination port because that's the server's well-known port for the service it's trying to connect to. The client will know the source port because it chooses it -- it's the port it sends the first packet *from*.

Comment: Hi, Noted your point. Client will know what is the destination's well known port. But consider a scenario where one client uses this well known port for connection request and data commn starts on this channel. Now when another client wants to have connection, it will send request on the same  well known port. Now if server wants to accepts this connection and get a new port (instead of well known port ) for this connection, is it possible. Or Server creates a new socket but will keep its source port same as well known port.

Comment: On the server side, the destination port of all packets received, and the source port of all packets sent, will be the server's well-known port.

Comment: Really thanks... I just wanted this answer. For one of our project, requirement states that client will send the port number(other than server's well known port) as destination port while requesting the connection. Server should check on their side, If the port sent by client is available then server should accept the connection on this port. I disagree to this point but want a strong explanation.

Comment: @EmbeddedDeveloper The port will always be available unless the client is broken. (There is no problem with re-using the same destination port to different IP addresses, even if the source IP address and port are the same.)

Comment: Sorry But it seems you misunderstood the question.. I intended to say that server is listening on port A and client sends the connection request on port B. Is this possible? Should server accept the connection and take the port B for that particular connection

Comment: @EmbeddedDeveloper The client sends the connection request *from* port B, *to* the server's well-known port. The server accepts the connection *on* its well-known port and responds *to* port B. That's how TCP works.

Answer (score -1):

When you connect to a server, you get a port number yourself, which is assigned to you by the system (unless you `bind` the socket before connecting). When the network stack of the server replies to your connection request, the "source" port is the new port number of the server, and the "destination" port of the message is your port. That's how the network stack on the client side knows what port the server has.

The new port number on the server used for your connection can not be set or changed by the actual server program, it's the network stack on the server machine that just grabs an available port number.

**Edit**: You might also want to read up a little on how [connections are established](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment), a.k.a. the three-way handshake.

Comment: There is no 'new port number of the server' and no 'grab[bing] an available port number'. The accepted socket uses the same port number as the listening socket.